# How to add one new attribute ' ref="gallery" ' to img tag with jquery?

Tags: jquery, attr

One Article includes many images, add one new attribute ( ref="gallery" ) to img tag with jquery when user view article, How do?

Example:
Change

```
<img src="test.jpg">
```

to

```
<img src="test.jpg" ref="gallery">
```

Comment: What do you mean by _when user view article_ ? Page load? Element is visible on the screen?

Comment: yes, open page(Page load?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('img').attr('ref', 'gallery');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#selectorId').attr(attname,attvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

For html try:

```
<img id="myimg" src="test.jpg">
```

And in script :

```
$('#myimg').attr('ref', 'gallery');
```